# How to customize the placement of compose in Gmail

Tags: gmail, css

I have **Reading Pane** enabled for *Right of inbox*, and that is slightly better, but what I need is to have the compose window over the inbox instead of below or over the reading pane.

**My current layout**
[image: Current Gmail layout]

**Desired layout**
[image: Desired Gmail layout]

The goal is to have the compose (reply) next to the reading instead of over it. I've been popping it out into a new window to move it, but then if I click on the reading window it goes behind. It seems like there should be a way to move the compose.

I suspect this is may require some custom CSS/JavaScript, and I'm OK with that. If so, please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with a really crude [Userscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript) via [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/). First time using Tampermonkey, and it works for now. I'm sure I'll revisit it later.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Gmail compose left layout 
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       Jim McKeeth
// @match        https://mail.google.com/*
// @run-at       document-start
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    // Your code here...
    GM_addStyle("body > div.dw > div > div > div > div.no { float: left !important; }")
})();
```